# Convert EditText (type phone) to String in Kotlin

Tags: android, string, kotlin, android-edittext

I have two `EditText` input fields (`inputType="phone"`) one for IP address and one for port number. I want to get the two values in a string form.

```
val ip : String = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ip).toString()
val port: String = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.port).toString()
println("IP AND PORT: $ip : $port")
```

The ouput is something like: `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText...`

Comment: findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ip) returns the text editor, not the text contained in it. Look for a text-property or something similar (not tested code, but it should be quite close): val ip: String = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ip).text.toString()

Comment: you can use direct through id like ip.text.toString()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are converting `EditText` to String. It is complex object not just a visible text. To get text from `EditText` You have to get `text` field from `TextView`. Like this:

```
val ip : String = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.ip).text.toString()
val port: String = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.port).text.toString()
```

`textView.text` is not a `String` but `Editable`, that's why You have to add `.toString()`